Girlfriend (boyfriend), lover, SO: 恋人 vs 彼 and 彼女
I have studied [very basic level] that [恋人]{こいびと} is girlfriend (or boyfriend), but also that [彼]{かれ}  is "he; boyfriend" and that  [彼女]{かのじょ} is "she; girlfriend".
I've checked jisho, and indeed the definitions are correct, but the example sentences it provides haven't helped at all to see the differences between these words.
Can they be used interchangeably or are there nuances not covered at my basic level?  Maybe 恋人 indicates a stronger / more intimate  relationship?  Is there a difference in formality (formal-polite vs colloquial-informal)?
More specifically, if I were to talk (or write) about my son's girlfriend, what would be the best choice: こいびと or かのじょ (like in "My son lives with his girlfriend in London.")

彼/彼女 is more of a colloquial expression (though not quite slang anymore), while 恋人 is an expression preferred in written documents and songs. 恋人 would be closer to "lover" in English. When casually talking about someone your relative is dating, 彼/彼女 would often sound more natural, but in serious conversations, 恋人 would also be appropriate. If you're conducting a formal or academic survey, 恋人 (or 付き合っている人) would be chosen.
EDIT: 愛人 seems to be simply translated as "lover" in some dictionaries, but today, it's primarily understood as a dated word for extramarital female partner (similar to "mistress" in English). Don't use this term unless you really know what you're doing.

You might also describe nuances of [愛人]{あいじん}.

Thank you for the clear answer (and the edit!)

In English, I feel like “lover” actually sits somewhere between 恋人 and 愛人. It’s not as explicit as “mistress” but it has a bit of implication that it’s a particularly passionate or informal relationship, more than 恋人 does. So I find 恋人 really hard to translate cleanly into English. I think “significant other” is probably the closest.
